# distributing lists with lists to remove lists of lists in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list:

```
example_list = [x, y, [1, 2, 3], [4,5,6]]
```

I need to turn into two lists:

```
j = [x, y, 1, 2, 3]
k = [x, y, 4, 5, 6]
```

This example list does not come up with regularity, only when there are two objects on one page that I am scraping--say contact_page.  Generally, there is only one contact so the list is:

`normal_example_list = [x, y, [1, 2, 3]]`

where 'x' comes from function 1, 'y' comes from function 2, and [1, 2, 3] comes from function 3 (contact_page) and I put them all together with normal_example_list.append()

when there is only one list from contact_page I can just flatten it out.  I am looking for a rule that would iterate over a list and remove the 1st list within the list and then the 2nd list within the list, while keeping all other variables in the list in their positions.

Thinking this through after retyping my query something like

```
p = []
for i in contact_page:
    p.append(x)
    p.append(y)
    p.append(i)
```

This would be more cumbersome to make functional in my code, but it may work.  I was hoping for a fix like (in words)

```
if example_list contains a list:
    new_list1 = [values common to both lists, [first list within list]]
    new_list2 = [values common to both lists, [second list within list]]
```

from that I can flatten it out.

Comment: What should happen when `i = [x, y, [1, [2,3]], [4,5,6], 7]`?

Comment: You need to supply more details about the flattening algorithm and types of input data. Do all the inputs look like `i` above? If not, what other forms are there and what are your expected outputs from them?

Comment: what is x,y? how do you know from which point you need to start flattening? For example  `[x,y,z,a,[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]` then it will do` [x,y,z,a,1,2,3],[x,y,z,a,4,5,6]` ? If so how do you know where to start? are `x,y,z,a` also `lists` or something else?

Comment: i = [x, y, [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], 7] would go to j = [x, y, 1, 2, 3, 7] k = [x, y, 4, 5, 6, 7] essentially [1, 2, 3] and [4, 5, 6] would be name, street address, city state zip each and x, y and 7 in the posited query would be the details about what those people were looking for.  if it is of any utility, the [1, 2, 3] and [4, 5, 6] are derived from the same script in a beautifulsoup script code.  Sometimes each instance has one name attached sometimes it is two or more.  I would want to be able to duplicate all of the others values to create two rows in my csv one for each person

Comment: What about when `i = [1, [2, 3], [4, 5], 6, [7,8]]`?

Comment: I have deliberately removed all other lists within the list so if there was i = 1, [2, 3], [4,5], 6, [7,8]] I would split into 3 lists a = [1, 2, 3, 6] b = [1, 4, 5, 6] c = [1, 7, 8, 6] the objects creating the lists in the lists will always be back to back because they are scraped from one page using one line of code on a while loop.

Comment: You should think about and describe the rule you need more clearly. For example, it appears you want "one list for each list in the original list, combined with all the elements in the list that aren't a list" - or something close to that.

Comment: Please consider representing your data using something more appropriate (e.g. `dict`) rather than using lists.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do? It's difficult to follow.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you want to extract all the lists from the input list and create a list for each, combined with all the non-list elements from the input list.

Something like:

```
xs = [1, 2, [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], 9, [10]]
singles = [x for x in xs if not isinstance(x, list)]
result = [singles + x for x in xs if isinstance(x, list)]
print(result)
```

Gets you:

```
[[1, 2, 9, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 9, 6, 7, 8], [1, 2, 9, 10]]
```

Comment: Classic copy paste mistake - thanks for the edit, though you may consider removing/updating the comment now that you've fixed it.